# Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_oci8_12c.dll. The specified module could not be found

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, netbeans

I am using netbeans+xampp+Xdebug

I have set up following xdebug configuration in php.ini

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\Program Files\PHP5\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.1-5.4-vc9-nts.dll"

xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
```

my c:\xampp\php folder contains all the required dlls

my php_oci8_12c.dll file is also placed on C:\xampp\php\ext

On restarting apache server from xampp . I am getting this error log on apache

```
[Sun Sep 18 01:49:21.075508 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 9372:tid 540] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Sep 18 01:49:21.191401 2016] [core:warn] [pid 9372:tid 540] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
Failed loading C:\Program Files\PHP5\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.1-5.4-vc9-nts.dll
ww.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mysql: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20151012\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_oci8_12c.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Sep 18 01:49:21.360576 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9372:tid 540] AH00455: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Sep 18 01:49:21.360576 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9372:tid 540] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec  9 2015 10:17:39
[Sun Sep 18 01:49:21.360576 2016] [core:notice] [pid 9372:tid 540] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Sun Sep 18 01:49:21.360576 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9372:tid 540] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 8204
[Sun Sep 18 01:49:22.191842 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 8204:tid 504] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
Failed loading C:\Program Files\PHP5\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.1-5.4-vc9-nts.dll
ww.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mysql: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=20131226\nPHP    compiled with module API=20151012\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\xampp\\php\\ext\\php_oci8_12c.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Sep 18 01:49:22.494042 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8204:tid 504] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Sun Sep 18 01:49:37.124565 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 800:tid 420] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Sep 18 01:49:37.240484 2016] [core:warn] [pid 800:tid 420] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
```

my php_xdebug-2.4.1-5.4-vc9-nts.dll file are properly in place in

C:\Program Files\PHP\v5.6  folder

My url also attech xdeug path fine 
like :
http://localhost/wordpress/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug

One post gave a solution to move the icu*.dll files to your Apache's bin directory .. but they are already there
what this error log is telling that I am missing ? please suggest . Regards

Answer (score 0):

This might be the problem of port that `apache` using.

Try these steps.

1. If you're using Skype disable it.
2. Try starting `xampp` as Administrator
3. Open `xampp` and click on <kbd>Config</kbd> then click on <kbd>Services & Ports Settings</kbd>. Change main port `80` to `8080` and SSL port `443` to `4433`. Then save and restart `xampp`
4. You can also change the `apache` 's default port settings by editing `.config` files. To do that follow the below steps

   - Open `xampp` click on <kbd>Config</kbd> button and select `httpd.conf`. Now this will open with Notepad. Now search for `Listen 80` and change this to `Listen 8080`
   - After that search for `ServerName localhost:80` and change it to `ServerName localhost:8080`
   - Save and exit.
   - Now once again click on <kbd>Config</kbd> and select `httpd-ssl.conf`. Search for `Listen 443`,`<VirtualHost _default_:443>` and `ServerName www.example.com:443` change `443` to `4433` save and exit.
   - And finally restart your `xampp`.

**Note**: If you change default port address it's necessary to mention which port number under `apache` is running. For example in your browser use `http://localhost:8080/project_name/index.php`